# ListView toggle choice mode

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a `ListView` (technically its a `ListFragment`, but I dont think that changes the question) which displays its results uisng a `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

```
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            getActivity(),
            R.layout.item,
            null,
            new String[] {"Name"},
            new int[] {R.id.Name}
            );

    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

(The Cursor is set/swapped in `onStart`).

I want to give the user the ability to toggle choice mode (which will than be used to display only the checked items).  A bit like an SMS application when you put messages in "batch mode" which allows you to select multiple conversations which can the be deleted, saved etc.  Do I set a new adapter or just change the existing ones properties?  the `ListView` will need re-drawing anyway to reflect changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a suprisingly simple answer.  The problem was I was calling the method in `onCreate` before `onCreateView` had inflated the `List`.  Stupdily this was just to test the function.  Once I moved it to `onStart` and later into its intended location in the `FragmentActivity` the following worked fine:

```
public void toggleAdapter()
{           
    ListView listView = getListView();

    if (listView.getChoiceMode() == ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE)
    {
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.item,
                dashboardCursor,
                new String[] {"Name"},
                new int[] {R.id.Name}
                );
    }
    else
    {
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.dashboard_list_item_multiple_choice,
                dashboardCursor,
                new String[] {"Name"},
                new int[] {R.id.Name}
                );
    }


    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do two things.

1. Use the ListView's setChoiceMode method to enable MULTI_SELECT on the ListView.
2. Create a 'Selector' to define a 'selected' or 'checked' state and set this as a style element on your R.layout.item.

Answer (score 1):

Like Vikram Bodicherla answer.

1. `setChoiceMode` to enable MULTI_SELECT on the ListView.
2. Set in your custom item layout a background that show the selected state like:

   ```
   android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
   ```

Comment: Work in previous version too, but you need to set a background that support selections states.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Provide an example that is working according to your method.